# Different performance of HTTP request in .NET Framework 4.7 vs .NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, http

I have a REST API in .NET Core and two test clients. The first client is in .NET Framework 4.7, and the second client is in .NET Core 3. I have the same code for the requesting API in both clients:

```
string data = "{\"SerializedMessage\":\"test\"}";
HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler();
hch.Proxy = null;
hch.UseProxy = false;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(hch);
HttpContent c = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:6001/api/Messages/TestMethod", c);
```

I have a breakpoint in API project in "TestMethod" method. When I try to call TestMethod from the .NET Core client, it is much slower than when I try it with the .NET 4.7 client. Why is that?

Comment: can you articulate what "much slower" is here? numbers? Also: what does the server do here? does it return anything? (I can see that you're not *looking* at a response, but that doesn't mean the server didn't send one)

Comment: Please, share the details of performance difference

Comment: "much slower" is few miliseconds vs 1.5 second - i'm not looking at response because i just waiting for breakpoint in API project and is see that in one case the breakpoint is hitted immediately and in second case is have to wait about 1.5 second. But i found solution - see my answer... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder` on the API project and after I switched to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder` the performance was better.